# Databinding in combobox

Tags: c#, 2-way-object-databinding

Reference:
[C# databinding on combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327117/c-databinding-on-combobox)

I have a similar situation. I have a form with few text boxes, combo boxes, check boxes. Initially I use to catch "changed" event (like, text_changed, selected_index_changed. etc) and sync the UI data with a backing object. I learned about Databinding and I bound all the UI elements to my backing object.

**Problem:** 
Based upon state of my UI, I was enabling and disabling "Submit" button which uses backing object to save to contents. But now, due to DataBinding, property of backing object does not change unless the control bound to that properly looses focus.

**Question**
Is there a standard way to solve this problem ? Or do I still need to catch "changed" event and set the value of backing object ?

Also, to make the form fault tolerant, I use to save the backing object every N seconds. But with DataBinding (given that the control which is on focus still havn't set its value to the backing object) I will be saving wrong data.

**What I tried**
Evey N seconds call this.validate() -> this does not work as it actually populate the old data in the control on focus.

----- NOTE ------

The backing object implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

and this is how I bind (not in designer) but in code.

Binding binding = new Binding("checked", solution, "InternalFlag");
checkBoxFlag.DataBindings.Add(binding);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change the property of binding which describes when to update the backend object from lost focus to value changed

[Data Source Update Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode.aspx)

```
binding = new Binding("checked", solution, "InternalFlag", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Comment: So, which property is that ? I tried to quickly find it, but I was unable to.

Comment: I have already tried setting "binding.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged" but that doesn't work either

Comment: I was setting it like .... this.checkBoxFlag.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;

Comment: But I noticed that if I set the DataSourceUpdateMode directly on the Binding object, it works ..

Comment: I would suggest instead of your current approach also try passing BindingMode in constructor of Binding and see what happens

Comment: I noticed that it works for TextBoxes, checkBoxes but not for combobox ..... this.comboBoxNetwork.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", inContext, "Network", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged); ..... does not work (do not update the backing object)